# Blocks Structure screen not displaying because there are too many blocks

Tags: blocks

I have a large D8 site and currently have about 400 blocks. When I got to the main Blocks Structure admin page
-- /admin/structure/block -- It now hangs up and will not display. I just get an error:

The application did not respond in time.

The site is hosted on Pantheon. I have a basic plan limited to 256M of application memory. We tested increasing the memory available to 512MB. That did not help, nor did the Pantheon Advanced Page Cache.

Any ideas on how to fix? Cache this specific admin page? Split up this page up into multiple pages like the Custom Block Library screen?

Thank you, Jeff

Comment: What is max_execution_time on /admin/reports/status/php and how long does it take to display the error message? If it doesn't take the full time then you need to remove external page caches like CDNs by accessing the site for admin purposes directly and configure a max execution time long enough to display the page.

Comment: thank you for this. The max_execution_time is 120 and the page error usually happen around 60 seconds, so it looks like the execution time is enough (120 seconds?) if I am reading it correctly.

Comment: The PHP max_execution_time doesn't matter as long as you have a shorter time limit set in a proxy between browser and web server.

Comment: If you don't know what I'm talking about ask the webhosting support how to access the site for admin tasks which take longer than 60 seconds.

Comment: Thank you, 4K4, will do, I really appreciate your help.